# Should /var/log be on an hdd partition when / is on an ssd?

Tags: partitioning, 14.10, ssd, log

I keep reading that `/var/log` should not be on an SSD as it gets written to all the time.

I'm installing Ubuntu and SSD and am wondering if I really need an extra partition for this folder on my HDD, and if so how big it should be?

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to expand this a little bit to also list any other directories under root which are recommended to be located in a non-SSD partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you reach such nonsense?  Unless you are running a very busy server, /var/log won't be written to *that* much.  You would have to be writing a few hundred MB/s to an SSD for several years to wear it out.  That would be an unfathomable amount of logs.

Answer (score 3):

That is going to be up to you... some options I have seen in the past: You can put /var/log/ on a ssd as it is by default, you can put it into a tmpfs and synch the contents to disk on shutdown, you can put /var/log on an on-disk filesystem with a large commit interval setting. Or mount it on a hdd all also with these options.

> and if so how big should it be?

This will totally depend on your usecase. Some hints: Plan to use logrotate? Plan to delete x days old logs? Plan to use Apache, MySQL, some other software that wants to keep a log?

If you want an exact answer on how large a /var/log/ needs to be you need to have a start date of creation of those logs, see how they increase over time and try to find a moment where you have a period of logging where you can start removing logfiles and the amount that the logs increase matches the amount you can remove. At that moment the logs will only grow if there is a specific problem you need to solve. Add some Mb for comfort and you have the size for your /var/log.